# Set default theme in classes extends FragmentActivity

Tags: java, android

Hello I want to switch between values-night and default values 
to load night theme(style.xml)
I am using this method for load night theme

```
 AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
```

it works fine with classes extends AppCompatActivity
but not in classes extends  FragmentActivity
is there any other way to load specific theme in FragmentActivity classes.

Comment: appcompat activity is a subclass of fragment activity, is there any specific reason why you're using the latter?

Comment: actually I am working on an old project ,have no idea why they are using fragmentActivity but I prefrer not to risk changing it to AppCompatActivity